# Insert character between div bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, character

I've a simple row where there's a label and two input type number

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Numero documento:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" id="firstDocumentNumber" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="number" id="secondDocumentNumber" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to insert a slash ( / ) between the two input type like this

[image]

Can anyone help me, please? Here there's the code I use [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/yXwIZ680f3)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. Also the link *doesn't work*

Comment: I had not noticed, I corrected right now. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: You still need to include the code in the question... *just enough* to demostrate what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I found is with CSS (tried with Bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="col-sm-1" id="secondDocumentNumberCont">
  <input type="number" id="secondDocumentNumber" class="form-control">
</div>
```

```css
#secondDocumentNumberCont:before {
    content: '/';
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -8px;
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
```

`margin-left` & `line-height` might require some tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use a span and format with size and align how you prefer..

```
<div class="site-index">
        <div class="body-content">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <br>
      <div class="container">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Numero documento:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="number" id="firstDocumentNumber" class="form-control">
        </div>
           <span class="col-sm-1 text-right" > / </span>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="number" id="secondDocumentNumber" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

or use an `add-on`

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">/</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```